# c segmentation fault fgets

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

```
int main( int argc, char** argv) {

        FILE *inFilePtr = fopen(*(argv + 1), "r");
        char *rawdata = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
        float *ary = malloc(sizeof(float) * 50);
        int counter = 0;
        float averageAns;
        int count = 0;


        while (count < 1 ){
            //fgets(rawdata, 50, inFilePtr); //I have tried both
            fscanf(inFilePtr, "%s", rawdata);
            *(ary + counter) = atof(strtok(rawdata, ","));
             counter++;
            *(ary + counter ) = atof(strtok(rawdata, NULL));
            counter++;
            *(ary + counter) = atof(strtok(rawdata, NULL));
             counter++;
            count++;
        }
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I keep getting a seg fault. It will seg fault even without the loop (the count < 1 was just to see if I could make it through once).

It will not work with fgets(), fscanf(). It seg faults when I change the stream in fgets to (stdin), and I mention this because I assumed the file * was the issue, but now I do not think it is. I have made the delimiter in my data file " " and ",".

If anyone know's what I did wrong, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You can use valgrind, gdb, or several other debugging tools to aid you... have you tried any of them?

Comment: also, why not just `ary[counter++] = atof(strtok(rawdata, NULL));`?

Comment: yes, and I'm not an expert using gdb. It gave me an error code that didn't help.

Comment: Did you check that inFilePtr isn't NULL?

Comment: it isn't null, i have a printf statement that prints the value of argv[1] and it is printing the file name I expect, also that is irrelvant because it won't work with stdin either.

Comment: @Vlad: if you're writing C on Linux/Unix you should really get familiarized with gdb. BTW your code crashes for me in the strtok() call (I think your two last calls are not correct).

Comment: david pointed out I didn't have the right arguments, but thanks for your help.

Comment: Why allocate memory for such a tiny array of characters?  Why not simplify life with `char rawdata[4096];` or something similar (or even `char rawdata[100];` if you're sure that'll be big enough)?

Comment: I fixed it, but because I am learning to allocate memory and to work with pointers, thus, my code is formatted that way.

Comment: Very closely related to [Segmentation fault reading from file with `fgets()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824138) and [`fgets()` errors segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825162/).  This is the oldest of the three; the others could be closed as duplicates of this.

Comment: NOT duplicates, not even related. This was an entirely different issue, thanks though. CLOSED for specific maybe. STOP TROLLING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `fscanf` is guaranteed to fail, as you have not provided an output argument. It should look like:

```
fscanf(inFilePtr, "%s", rawdata);
```

Your calls to `strtok` are also invalid. To continue tokenising the same string, the **first** argument of `strtok` should be `NULL`; `strtok` expects the second argument to still be a valid string.

Each of these issues would cause a segfault on their own. To ease your debugging in future, I would suggest either using a debugger and setting a breakpoint after the statement you are debugging, or commenting out other lines which you might expect to segfault (which typically includes anything that does anything with strings, if your code is in a fragile state.

Also, as a matter of style,

```
*(ary + counter)
```

Is normally written

```
ary[counter]
```

Comment: i have an output argument, but the strtok is probably the issue. thanks i'll try it

Comment: Ah, didn't see the edit. Given that it didn't work with the (valid) `fgets` call, it probably is the `strtok`.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your malloc calls with (char *)

maybe, just maybe: `ary[counter++] = atof(strtok(rawdata, ","));`