# Seg Fault error reading from file with fgets

Tags: c, fgets

```
//declare double pointer so that create array can "return" an array
int **aryReturn;
int size;
char trashdata[100];

//open file
FILE *inFilePtr = fopen(*(argv + 1), "r" );

if (inFilePtr != NULL)
    printf(" the value of argv 1 is %s \n", argv[1]); 

while (fgets(trashdata, sizeof(int) * 10, inFilePtr) != NULL){
    fgets(trashdata, 10, inFilePtr);
    size++;
}
```

can anyone tell me why my loop condition will not work! I get a seg fault that says fp(0x0) at fgets.
I have tried

```
while (!feof(inFilePtr))
```

And I basically get the same error, but it says feof is the problem.

My file seems to open correctly because the if statement prints.. and argv has the expected file name

Comment: First off, why are you calling fgets in the loop body and also in the loop condition? Second, it should append a null character after each call.

Comment: So when I use fgets in a condition, does it still get the data and store it? Also, My error still occurs without it.

Comment: Do you see the `the value of argv[1]` message?  You should not use `inFilePtr` if it is NULL; that will lead to crashes.  The chances are high that you are failing to open the file.

Comment: When you call `fgets()`, it stores the data into the string (unless there's no data to read).  It (`fgets()`) has no clue whether it is being called from a `while`, an `if` or just inline.

Comment: Yes I see the value of argv[1], ok thanks for the fgets advice. how do I check to see if the file opened correctly then?

Comment: You should note that `size` is not initialized to any value.

Comment: Sorry... Got last in my copy and paste, it is intialized.

Comment: I think you need to provide an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) so that people can help.  You say you've skipped the initialization of `size` (and `aryReturn`).  That isn't critical to the code we can see; it certainly is not the source of your segmentation fault.  But as we can't see what you've got, it is hard to help more than we have.  (You should take a look at the sizes passed to `fgets()`; neither is likely to exceed the size of the array `trashdata`—which is an appalling name for your input data—so you aren't crashing because of a buffer overflow.)

Comment: Very closely related to [C segmentation fault `fgets()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700487/) and [`fgets()` errors segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825162/).

Comment: @Jonathan: actually aryReturn *was* the source of his segmentation fault.  The clue is in the comment above it where he says it will be used to "return" an array. He passed aryReturn (a wild pointer) to a function that then indirected through it to write a pointer to a malloc()'ed array of int's. The wild pointer hit nothing crucial, so he thought his program worked fine. Then he added some code, things moved around in memory, and now the wild pointer is hitting something important, hence the wild goose chase in gdb.

Comment: @RonBurk: I take your word for it; in the code shown, it is an unused variable.  I certainly agree that it the `aryReturn` is not initialized (or allocated) in the fragment given.  I've not studied the related questions hard enough to know whether they give the missing information.  That's the trouble with non-SSCCE code; you can't tell what's missing that's important.

Comment: @RonBurk You are correct sir.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see a few problems...

- `size` is not initialized
- calling `gets()` twice in a row seems odd, see `feof()`
- you aren't doing anything after testing the `fopen()` result against NULL, so the first `gets()` could bomb out for that reason ... do you get that message?

Only the last thing seems likely to throw an exception, but my philosophy is always *fix the known problems and retest* ... it's a waste of time to predict interactions between bugs.

Comment: `inFilePtr` is tested for `!= NULL`, but the code doesn't take evasive action (like returning — it appears to be code for a function `create_array()`) if the open fails.

Comment: I already fixed size, I tried feof and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm unsure what's wrong honestly, the filePtr isn't NULL and that's all I know how to test.. I tried feof and fgets...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the filename that you are providing in the argument either does-not exists or some access violations. You can check this by printing the errno just after doing the fopen command.

```
fprintf (stderr, "Couldn't open file %s; %s\n", argv[1], strerror (errno));
```

also can you try this code once:

```
#include<errno.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int **aryReturn;
    int size=0;
    char trashdata[100];

    //open file
    FILE *inFilePtr = fopen(*(argv + 1), "r" );

    printf(" the value of argv 1 is %s \n", argv[1]);
    if (inFilePtr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Couldn't open file %s; %d\n", argv[1],errno);
        exit(0);
    }
    while (!feof(inFilePtr)){
    fgets(trashdata, 10, inFilePtr);
    printf("%s",trashdata);
    size++;
    }
}
```