# Fgets errors seg fault

Tags: c, fgets

Is there any reason that a program, which compiled earlier, should seg fault at a point because of fgets? I changed no code related to it AT ALL. Suddenly I believe it is failing to open the file, but I tested it with the file like fifteen minutes ago.... All I did was add a search function, so I don't understand what the issue is.....

Could it be the server I'm connecting to over PuTTy?

```
int createarray( int **arrayRef, FILE *fptr){
    int size = 0, i;
    char rawdata[100];

    while (fgets(rawdata, 99, fptr) != NULL){
        size++;
    }

    rewind(fptr);
    *arrayRef = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
     fgets(rawdata, 99, fptr);
     *(*arrayRef + i) = atoi(rawdata);
    }


    return size;
}


      int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {  //main call

    // declare variable to hold file
    FILE *inFilePtr = fopen(*(argv + 1), "r");
    int **aryHold;
    int numElements, sortchoice, key, foundindex;

    // Call function to create array and return num elements
    numElements = createarray(aryHold, inFilePtr);
```

This is the code that compiled, performed correct, and hasn't been changed since. GDB says there is an error with fgets.

Comment: RELEASE YOUR ANGER (ALSO YOUR CODE PL0X OR WE'RE JUST GUESSING)

Comment: We can't help you unless you actually show us what the problem is.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I think fptr is empty. can u show me the function call.

Comment: GDB says its empty, but I CANNOT figure out why... it wasn't earlier.. Sure hold on.

Comment: The file which you are accessing is exists in the same directory and it is having read permission?

Comment: yes, nothing should have changed.

Comment: the argument you are passing should be exact file name including extension. edit the code and directly give file name to open instead of passing as argument. Then see if its working or not.

Comment: In case of doubt, **print** the data you just read.  If you don't see what you were expecting to see, you know something went wrong.  `printf("In: <<%s>>\n", rawdata);` in the loop after each `fgets()`.  Also, you are (once again, or still) not checking that the file was opened successfully.  **Always** check that any `fopen()`-type function succeeds.

Comment: I cannot compile currently but when i could printing argv[1] gave me what i expected.

Comment: What does "I cannot compile currently" mean?  You've no longer got access to the computer with the compiler?  Or your code no longer compiles?

Comment: @Vlad without compiling frequently with modified changes its difficult to figure out the bug.

Comment: This is rather closely related to your previous questions: [C segmentation fault `fgets()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700487/) and [Segmentation fault error reading from file with `fgets()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824138/).  You don't seem to be paying enough attention to the advice you are being given.

Comment: I am paying attention and honestly I don't appreciate the attitude (If you don't want to help, you don't have to be pretentious).  I CANNOT compile due to a seg fault. I can run the program fine if I remove the fgets and the debugger is telling me that fgets is the problem, specfically that the filePtr is (0x0). It worked earlier and FOR some reason, it just stopped working and I didn't change anything related to it at all. This question is about general fgets() errors and unrelated to my previous question.

Comment: @Vlad fptr is empty means the file is not opened. May be the file don't have read permission, or it no longer exists in the directory. If you can't compile the code then enjoy Segmentation Fault. No other way to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the reason it use to "work" is you were clobbering an unimportant memory location. Changing your code shifted things around and now you are clobbering something important.

You're passing an uninitialized pointer to createarray(). You wanted to do something like:

```
int* aryHold;
//...
... createarray(&aryHold ...
```

BTW, many compilers have the ability to catch this kind of error for you. If you haven't already, you might want to see if your compiler has an error checking option that could have saved you hassling with this (and perhaps find some other code that only "works" accidentally).